# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason my rails app is trying to access an action in my controller that I did not plan for which in return gives me a routing error. I am using the resource feature in rails to get all my routes.

[image]

This is what I have in my controller

[image]

Finally when I did rake routes I got the following routes, I am wondering why I am getting the routing error when it clearly shows me the right route in the console
[image]

EDIT: Below is my routes.rb
[image]

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb?

Comment: Add @users = User.all to your index method. Your user controller needs to recognize that /users corresponds to this action. 

Give that a shot.

Comment: Tried that but had no luck, actually I dont think that is needed since I set user as a resource. The index should automatically show all the users as stated in console output

Comment: Good point - have you tried explicitly stating in your resource:  get '/users', :to => "users#index" ?

Comment: My question would be, why is it trying to access the edit action in the users controller? Isn't it supposed to map to the index action?

Comment: Yes, it should. Does users/1/edit or users/1 work?

Comment: Yeap I just did and it also did not work. I even tried match '/users', to: "users#index" but that also did not seem to work

Comment: users/1 and users/1/edit seems to work. Let me try some additional debugging and would let you know. By the thanks for your help though

Comment: No problem - I'm new to Rails, so sorry I couldn't help more. Maybe check your logs to make sure /users is mapping to the GET action

Comment: Try restarting your server. This is pretty bizarre behavior.

Comment: re-starting the sever also did not seem to work...Hmmmm I'll keep it updated once I figure it out

Comment: Probably what is causing this mistake is that you matched the root to users#new,
so that when you access localhost:3000/users, it probably causes some confusion. Try to comment that `root to:` line and see what happens

Comment: Good debugging tip @JohnFurtado, I tried that but still had no luck.

Comment: Are you sure that your `signed_in_user` filter is not rendering something that has to do with editing users?

Comment: can you show your index view? Maybe you have some edit link there. Do you have edit action?

Comment: Basically signed in user does the following `def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location #Method to find where the user was trying to reach
        redirect_to root_path 
      end
    end`

Answer (score 2):

I have a same error

You can check in file views/layout/_header.html.erb

My error is <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>

but it have to <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>